# How to convert old Japanese text encodings?

Tags: text, unicode, encoding, character

I run MacBook Pro under 10.6.7, and I am competent in Unix.  I have old Japanese text files in various encodings (EUC, SJS, New-JIS) that I can no longer read or display.  The old program jconv.c does not help, since it only converts among these encodings.  Is there a way to convert them (or any one of them) to the current "normal" Japanese text that can be seen in TextEdit, etc.?  I have set the Terminal preferences to SJS and EUC (can't find NewJIS), among others, including UTF-8.  Eleanor

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you look into [iconv](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/iconv.1.html) for doing such conversions.

Comment: Thanks!  That works fine!  I would never have known -- you're a big help!  Eleanor

Answer (score 1):

nkf is a Linux command line program which can meet your requirement.
I am sure it is available at Debian. So you can download sorce code from the Net.